# Iphone: Application feasibility

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, feasibility

I am very new to developing apps on the Iphone (In-fact I am new to application development all together). I would like to know what the feasibility for an idea for a app on the iphone is.

1)The application would allow users to download content (audio or if possible video files) onto the device.
2)Each of these files will need to be purchased before downloading, at a fixed price.
3)The user can then play the downloaded files on the device.

Is such an app possible to be made on the Iphone?
If so can anyone give me pointers on how the payment procedure should be, and how revenue will be shared with apple?

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, that sounds very possible.The users would pay you directly through a credit card for the files.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I would like to know would apple be taking 30% off each purchase of the content or is it just for the application.

Comment: That is just for purchasing the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already a registered apple-Developer, have a look at the [InAppPurchase(IAP) ProgrammingGuide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the iOS-Devcenter.

The purchase of any content must be handled through IAP. 
This is written in the App Store Review Guidelines, Item 11.2 (Because I'm new, I can't provide a link. Sorry for that)

It is not possible that users pay you directly.